# How to logging unicode dictionary from elasticsearch-py?

Tags: python, logging, unicode, python-unicode, elasticsearch-py

By default, [elasticsearch-py](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py) logs output dictionary as `json` dumped like:

```
{'key': '2016\u5e747\u670829\u65e5'}
```

While I'd like to see the result as following:

```
{'key': '2016年7月29日'}
```

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

Python 2.7.10

```
$ pip freeze | grep elasticsearch
elasticsearch==1.9.0
```

Comment: It depends on how that was dumped and the actual content of the string.  Are those Unicode escapes or literal backslashes?  Python 2 or 3? Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MarkTolonen Sorry for late response. I've found that latest elasticsearch-py package [has improved the unicode logging output](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/commit/c305dc5587963bc9e41ae8cf35bb6eff5afb199e), while I'm still using elasticsearch 1.x. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Cockcrow Maybe post that as an answer and accept it so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elasticsearch-py` package has improved the unicode logging output.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/commit/c305dc5587963bc9e41ae8cf35bb6eff5afb199e